# Settings on ContainerPart on new type

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to create a new content type in a migration that has a ContainerPart attached with some settings already applied.

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("NewType",
    cfg => cfg
        .DisplayedAs("New Type")
        .WithPart(typeof(TitlePart).Name)
        .WithPart(typeof(ContainerPart).Name)
            .WithSetting("ContainerPartSettings.ItemsShownDefault", "False")
        .WithPart(typeof(CommonPart).Name)
        .WithPart(typeof(IdentityPart).Name)
        .Creatable()
        .Listable()
    );
```

ItemsShownDefault, after the migration, stays at its default value of True.

I've tried a few different variations of this:

- Renaming "ContainerPartSettings" to other versions like ContainerSettings, ContainerTypePartSettings
- Not using the typeof() function and specifying the part with a direct string

From what I can tell, ContainerSettings uses a different method to store its values compared to others like AutorouteSettings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, your are chaining the settings on your **type** instead of the **part**:

```
.WithPart(typeof(ContainerPart).Name) // close the WithPart function

    // which means the following line is chained to the type
    .WithSetting("ContainerPartSettings.ItemsShownDefault", "False")
```

To fix this, do it like this:

```
.WithPart(typeof(ContainerPart).Name, part => part

    // inside the ContainerPart context
    .WithSetting("ContainerPartSettings.ItemsShownDefault", "False")
) // Close ContainerPart context

.WithPart(..)
```

---

If you did mean to set the settings on the type instead of the part, use the `ContainerTypePartSettings` class that is defined [here](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/6720b71cf3474a9a7b8a8cc9a99d58b1e733acfa/src/Orchard.Web/Core/Containers/Settings/ContainerSettings.cs#L50):

```
.WithPart(typeof(ContainerPart).Name)

// Set settings on the type instead of the part
.WithSetting("ContainerTypePartSettings.ItemsShownDefault", false)
```